# Force Reload page on wpf Application

Tags: wpf

I am trying to reload the page but receiving error: System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService' does not contain a definition for 'refresh'

What am I missing? Below is the code I am using.

```
using System.Windows.Navigation;

public void btnReload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Microsoft.Phone assembly or the PresentationFramework assembly?  Microsoft.Phone's implementation of NavigationService does not have a Refresh method.

[Navigation Service Class MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Ianschol! I am using Microsoft phone assembly? Can I use PresentationFramework? or is there any other way?

Comment: If you're targeting Windows Phone, afaik you're locked into either using a hack like this one: [link](http://danielvaughan.org/post/Refresh-a-WP7-PhoneApplicationPage.aspx) ...or replacing the DataContext for the page.  If you're not targeting Windows Phone but have the Phone dll in your project for some reason, you can remove the Microsoft.Phone.dll reference from your project and use PresentationFramework instead.